# Parsing an XML file with XMLHttpRequest.responseText won't display on div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, api

I'm trying to parse a XML document from an API link....

However when I try to use the code div.innerHTML=request.responseText it won't parse the text into the div unlike it does in the alert which is called in the line before.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
var url = 'http://www.bea.gov/api/data/?&userID=XXXXX&method=GETDATASETLIST&ResultFormat=XML&';
    div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.onload = function() {
    data = request.responseText;
    alert(data);
    div.innerHTML = data;
};
request.send();
</script>
```

Any reason why the alert function is working but the div.innerHTML function is not working for the request.responseText?

Comment: You are misusing the word "parse" ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)). You don't seem to want to parse anything here. Explain what you expect to happen when you do `div.innerHTML = request.responseText`.

Comment: Sorry for the misuse. I expect it to copy the whole XML document as a string and update the content of the html div element. Since it seems the alert function was able to do this, I expected the above would suffice. Here is a snippet of the XML string from the alert.

<Dataset DatasetName="IIP" DatasetDescription="International Investment Position"/><Dataset DatasetName="GDPbyIndustry" DatasetDescription="GDP by Industry"/>

Comment: that xml string has no text in it so what are your expectations? looks like you would need to loop through the attributes and convert to html. If that's the case would first see if API has JSON output , it's a little bit easier to work with ( not greatly significant though)

Comment: The XML format is a business need.

The alert(request.responseText) was able to display the above sample xml content. However when using div.innerHTML = request.responseText to display the same xml content as string as the alert, it did not work?

Comment: If you assign to `div.innerHTML` you force the browser to interpret the string *as if it was HTML*. And the default action for unknown HTML elements (like `<Dataset>`) is to output nothing and move on. Since there is no other text in your XML the browser displays nothing. Works as designed. If you want to display the XML *as if it were plain text*, assign to the `div.textContent` property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://www.bea.gov/api/data/?&userID=XXXXX&method=GETDATASETLIST&ResultFormat=XML&';
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.onload = function() {
    data = request.responseText;
    console.log(data);
    div.textContent = data;
};
request.send();
```

This should work.